# Different Internet Speeds

Tags: internet, itunes, download, speed

My family has an internet plan that is very old. We don't have the newer plans that have really fast internet speeds. Usually my download speeds are at 90 kb/sec. The highest download speeds that I can get that are consistent are MAX.114 kb/sec. But thats if no one else is on the network and I'm not doing anything, but that download.

Right now, I am downloading something on iTunes and it is going up to (and over) 900 kb/sec.

What is going on? Am I not getting the download speeds that I am paying for? If that is happening than what can I do to use my full speed. Is iTunes doing something?

I really want a faster internet as when watching videos they buffer half of the time.

If it is possible that my internet could be faster than what can I do to make it faster.

Thanks!

*I also have a picture of the download speeds on my computer. I can add in a link to it if that is helpful.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=900+kilobits+to+kilolbytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kB/s` and `kb/s` isn't the same. `B` is for bytes, `b` is for bits. One byte is equal to 8 bits. iTunes gives you 900 kb/s, which is around 112 kB/s. It's exactly the same speed, but in different units.